# Why some Tailwind classes are working and others aren't?

Tags: css, frameworks, tailwind-css, css-frameworks, tailwind-in-js

I haven't found a solution that works. I followed the steps on the Tailwind installation page. I've linked everything. I know that Tailwind is being applied to the index.html since the font is different and I'm able to style the background color of the header. But that's all that has worked so far. If I try to add any additional classes (ex. flex, font-weight), to the header or anything else, there's no change.

My HTML head and header:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="./assets/css/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./assets/css/src/input.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Room-3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Class "flex" isnt working -->
    <header class=" flex bg-slate-400">
        <h1>Room-3</h1>
        <p id="what-we-do">What We Do</p>
        <button>Get Started</button>
    </header>
    <script src="./tailwind.config.js"></script>
</body>
```

My tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

My input.css:

*Note: @tailwind is red and underlined in each instance, so I suspect the problem has something to do with this file*

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Answer (score 2):

Apply path in tailwind config file.

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content:{
    relative: true, 
    files: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./layout/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}", ==> I am using outside component So when i add path it working.
 
  ],},
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

In the documentation of tailwind it is written also
Don’t use extremely broad patterns.

[image: see what avoid]

[check docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration)

Comment: Yes, it's the content option in tailwind.config.js. I use nx and angular and this worked for me: "./libs/yourLib/src/lib/**/*.html" (change yourLib to your library name)

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to work fine.If the background is working then the rest should work as well

There may be mistakes in the class names.

Try this code:

```
<header class="flex items-center justify-around bg-slate-400">
  <h1 class="">Room-3</h1>
  <p id="what-we-do">What We Do</p>
  <button class="text-2xl">Get Started</button>
</header>
```

The output goes like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as all the classes you mentioned i.e. `flex, bg-slate-400` all are working. This means that tailwind css is installed properly on your system.

> To watch `flex` is working, you can add `flex-col` or `justify-evenly` to give flex a direction.

However if you add `font-weight` , this will not work as it is not any class, you can add `font-bold, font-medium,..`  will work.

A working example is given below

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <header class="flex justify-evenly bg-slate-300">
        <h1 class="font-extrabold">Room-3</h1>
        <p id="what-we-do">What We Do</p>
        <button class="font-extralight">Get Started</button>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I was working on a Laravel app in my local development environment using phpStorm, and the changes I was making to classes were not rendering in my browser. Tailwind will only load classes that are used within the code, BUT unless you are running npm, Tailwind will not recognize what you are typing into your IDE...

```
npm run dev
```